# Regex to check string contain certain value php

Tags: php, regex

Can someone help me with a php regular expression? I need to match pairs of brackets. For example, it should only match `"[abc #123]:"`

```
"Re: [abc #123]: question"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to match pair of brackets, then why is there `:` in the expected match? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What about nested brackets? Do you have them? If yes, how you want to treat them?

Comment: @RohitJain its just format, i just tried to make reply system , this will be in mail subject, so i could map this "123" with question

Comment: nope dnt want nested brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need groups

```
/\[([a-z]+)\ \#([1-9]+)\]/g
```

else

```
/(\[[^\]]+\])/g
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can Use This

```
$str="Re: [abc #123]: question";
$strout=preg_replace_callback("~\[(.*)\]:~si",function($m){echo $m[1];return $m[1];}," ".$str." ");
```

for different input

```
 $str="[tag1] / [tag2]";
 preg_replace_callback("#\[(.*?)\]#",function($m){print_r($m);return $m[1];}," ".$str." ");
```

Comment: This matches too much. For example it matches `[fname]\n Last name: [lname]`. Probably not desired.

Comment: make is non greedy by applying an ?. e.g. "~\[(.*)\]:~si" -> "~\[(.*?)\]:~si"

Comment: @JanDvorak my code Return and echo inside of []: such **Re: [abc #123]: question** return **abc #123**

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur your code will output `tag1] / [tag2` if the input is `in [tag1] / [tag2], we want only "tag1"`

Comment: @FaishalSaiyed you didn't specify that. Closevoting as "not a real question"